# Valid android certificate using IP

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, x509certificate

In my job we run a private PKI with an internal CA to sign our server certificates. While developing an Android app which communicates with a REST api over https I setup a dev server using an 192.168.x.x IP and issued a certificate for it. So I had:

- The CA certificate with a CN of 'Custom CA'
- The server cert with CN 192.168.0.3

Then I followed [Android docs on setting up a TrustStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems) and got the app to communicate over https in an Android 4.0.4 device.
When I tested the app in a device running Android 4.4 (KitKat) the server could not be validated.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Another way to do with is to set up host names even in your development environments. (Even DNS servers than are visible globally can return IP addresses that are private, so you could set up "test1.mycompany.com" to be 192.168.0.3.)

Comment: You should *not* place hostnames in `Common Names (CN)`. That's deprecated by both the IETF and CA/Browser Forums. Instead, place the DNS name in `Subject Alternate Names (SAN)`. Use the `CN` for a friendly name like 'Example Widgets' (I personally don't use a legal name like 'Example Widgets, LLC' because its a friendly name often displayed to users).

Answer (score 2):

So after digging a bit on [RFC2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) and [RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-7.2) I found that the DefaultHostnameVerifier implementation in [APIv14 (4.0.4)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.0.4_r2.1/luni/src/main/java/javax/net/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier.java) checks the host against CN section and if it's not a match it will look for SAN entries of **DNS** type but not IP type. [APIv19 (4.4.4)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.4.4_r1/luni/src/main/java/javax/net/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier.java) will check IP hosts against SAN IP entries.

So I added an IP SAN entry 192.168.0.3 to the server cert and signed it against the CA and got the 4.4 device to communicate over HTTPS.

Comment: Ah, I see you figured this out... By the way, the public CAs we most often encounter in the wild for websites and related services do *not* follow the RFCs, like 5280 and 6125. They follow their own standard developed at the CA/Browser Forums. Take a look at the CA/B's [Baseline Requirements Documents](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) and [EV Guide](https://cabforum.org/extended-validation-2/). If you are working on the web, then those are the standards that you should follow (and not the all-encompassing RFCs which accomodate all past and future worst practices).

Comment: "So I added an IP SAN entry 192.168.0.3 to the server cert and signed it against the CA and got the 4.4 device to communicate over HTTPS" - this is a different issue. According the CA/B's Baseline Requirements Documents, there is some special handling when using IPs (as opposed to FQDNs). I *think* the IP needs to be in *both* the `CA` and `SAN`. But using a RFC 1918 private address violates best practices. Private addresses should not be used.

Comment: @jww Thanks for pointers on the CA/Browser forums. Regarding the IP case, the RFC states that it MUST be in the SAN to be valid. I don't know what CA/B's say about it.